# Opengraph og:image unable to change URL

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

We have a problem when users update the `og:image` for an article.

The [Open Graph Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) picks up the new image, and our CMS triggers a scrape using the API endpoint [documented here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#update).

But for existing shares, Facebook renders a placeholder and doesn't update to the new `og:image` URL. Which means if the original image is deleted in our CMS, Facebook shows a blank placeholder:

[image: Image showing the blank Facebook placeholder where our og image should be]

[Facebook's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#update) says:

> You can always edit an object's properties, with two exceptions:
>
> Title: Once 50 actions (likes, shares and comments) have been associated with an object, you won't be able to update its title
>
> Type: An object's type can't be changed once it's been used in a story
>
> If you want to update an image for an object, we strongly suggest that the URL to the image be different than the original image URL. Caching may prevent the image from being updated.

Images uploaded to our CMS always have unique filenames, and are served from an Amazon S3 bucket via Cloudflare.

If we don't delete the original image from our server, in existing shares Facebook continues to use the original in spite of the `og:image` changing and us telling FB to re-scrape the URL.

How can we get the image to update?

Twitter and Linkedin do not have a problem as they appear to cache the original image on their servers, so once we delete the file they continue to serve the original `og:image`. That's fine - but Facebook needs to show an image.

Comment: _“How can we get the image to update?”_ - for already existing posts, _you_ can’t do that at all, of course. (Want me to replace that cute kitten image I used for my link that you shared yesterday with one saying “buy ch34p v14gr4 here” tomorrow? Of course you don’t.) The user/page that shared your link can manually request a refresh of the share attachment via the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Try `?v=2` at the end of `og:image` url.